# Double to string and back causes error

Tags: c#

This simple program

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var smallDouble = double.MinValue;
        Console.WriteLine(smallDouble);
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(double));
        var convertedValue = converter.ConvertFrom(smallDouble.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(convertedValue);
    }
}
```

Gives the following error

```
sh-4.3# mono main.exe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
-1.79769313486232E+308                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

Unhandled Exception:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
System.Exception: -1.79769313486232E+308 is not a valid value for Double. ---> System.OverflowException: Number overflow.                                                                                                                              
  at System.Double.Parse (System.String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0                                                                                                                             
  at System.ComponentModel.DoubleConverter.ConvertFromString (System.String value, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo format) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0                                                                                     
  at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom (ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0                                                           
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom (ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0                                                           
  at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom (System.Object o) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0                                                                                                                                               
  at Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Exception: -1.79769313486232E+308 is not a valid value for Double. ---> System.OverflowException: Number overflow.                                                                                           
  at System.Double.Parse (System.String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0                                                                                                                             
  at System.ComponentModel.DoubleConverter.ConvertFromString (System.String value, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo format) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0                                                                                     
  at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom (ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something? This is came up in a serialization test.

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441782/why-does-double-tryparse-return-false-for-a-string-containing-double-maxvalue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parsing is failing since the converted string value of `double.MinValue` is not exactly what is suppose to be. It is getting rounded. Use:

```
 var convertedValue = converter.ConvertFrom(smallDouble.ToString("r"));
```

See: [The round-trip ("R") format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The round-trip ("R") format specifier is used to ensure that a numeric
>   value that is converted to a string will be parsed back into the same
>   numeric value. This format is supported only for the Single, Double,
>   and BigInteger types.